# process is not defined in lite-server with redux

Tags: angular, redux, systemjs, lite-server

When using the default SystemJS config from Angular 2 RC.5, the lite-server throw an error of **process is not defined** if add `redux` as dependency. Has anyone experienced this? Here is the trace stack:

`(index):43 Error: ReferenceError: process is not defined
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/redux/lib/index.js:38:5)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/redux/lib/index.js:47:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/redux/lib/index.js:48:3)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/components/ng-redux.js:14:15)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/redux/lib/index.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/components/ng-redux.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/index.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/actions/session.actions.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js`

Comment: Can you share your system.config.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Stack Overflow record, repeating my response to the same question on github: https://github.com/angular-redux/ng2-redux/issues/202

Try putting this in system.config.js:

```
var map = {
  /* ... */
  'ng2-redux': 'node_modules/ng2-redux',
  'redux':     'node_modules/redux',
};

var packages = {
  /* ... */
  'ng2-redux': { main: 'lib/index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'redux':     { main: 'dist/redux.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```